# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0, 31399, 50) for Tensor 'Placeholder_22:0', which has shape '(1, 50)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to do a multivariate linear regression and I am having some issues. Namely, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0, 31399, 50) for Tensor 'Placeholder_22:0', which has shape '(1, 50)'
```

I tried `X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 50])`, but it also create error.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import csv
from math import sin

a = []
A = 0.01
i = A
cnt = i
while i<=3.14:
    q = []
    q.append(cnt)
    for j in range(2,101,2):
        #ins = round(i**j,j)
        q.append(i**j)
    q.append(sin(i))
    
    a.append(q)
    print(q)
    #print('##',a)
    i += A
    cnt += A

with open('sinL.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for i in a:
        writer.writerow(i)

init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

data = pd.read_csv('sinL.csv', sep=',')

xy = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)

x_data = xy[:, 1:-1]
y_data = xy[:, [-1]]

X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 50])
Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([50,1], mean=0.01, stddev=0.01), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1]), name="bias")

hypothesis = tf.matmul(X, W) + b

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-10)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(11):
        cost_, hypo_, _ = sess.run([cost,hypothesis, train] , feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})
        if step%10==0:
            print(step,cost_,hypo_)

print result::
0 370825000000.0 [[-1.66055486e-01]
 [-1.66046411e-01]
 [-1.66033715e-01]
 [-1.66017383e-01]
...
[ 2.69337825e+06]
 [ 3.70506525e+06]
 [ 5.08823150e+06]]
10 nan [[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]
...
[nan]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
```

Comment: If you're no longer getting the same error, you should edit the question to indicate that.

Comment: It looks like it's now working, but just producing NaN loss values. Your method of generating the sin values give extremely large and extremely small values so I suggest you change it.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally recommend against using TensorFlow 1.x code and moving to Tensorflow 2.x code using the built-in Keras API, because it tends to be easier and simpler to use.

However, the error you're seeing is because you define your input `X` to be of shape `(1, 50)` or `(None, 50)` whereas the actual input is 3-D, even though the first dimension is of size 0, so no data is actually in the array. I think there is an issue with your data loading into `x_data` and `y_data`. So verify that there is valid data in `x_data` and `y_data` and that `_x` and `_y` are 2-D arrays and it then it should work.

Comment: I changed the code like this:
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 50])
Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1]) 
W = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([50,1]), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1]), name="bias")
But training gives me all nan result... why...? I tried learning_late=1e-10~30 but it still

Comment: You should update the original question with the changed code and result.